# Can I post code on Stack Overflow without asking a question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community-wiki, code

I started to create a post on the regular stackoverflow site regarding creating extensions for a StringBuilder. Basically, the original code I had written was in VB.NET and I needed to port it to C#. Well, while I was writing up the post, I figured it out on my own. Can I place this code on stackoverflow for all to use? If the answer is yes, should I create it as a 'community wiki' post?

### edit

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272534/how-do-i-port-an-extension-in-vb-net-to-c/1272544) to the question I posted. Does this suit the bill? (sorry I want to make sure I do this right!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that as long as it's not asked/answered already.
You should post the question and then answer it yourself.

No need for Community Wiki.

Comment: So just post a "Here is a useful extension for StringBuilders" 'question'?

Comment: The main rule is that you phrase the post as a question, then post the code in the answer. "How do I make an extension that does ___ in string builder?", then post the answer below.

Comment: I added a recomendation, post your question and then answer it with the solution

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is first write a question.

> ### How do I port some VB.NET code to C#?
>
> *Your question here*

Then post an answer to that question.

Make sure that you don't make the question or answer too specific to your problem, otherwise it may not be helpful to others..